# How to check whether the wifi is connected to specific SSID

Tags: android, android-layout

I read this solution : [How to check network connection enable or disable in WIFI and 3G(data plan) in mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373930/how-to-check-network-connection-enable-or-disable-in-wifi-and-3gdata-plan-in-mo)   .BUT, it just check whether wifi network is connected or not. How to check whether the wifi is connected to the specific SSID or not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code is similar, again use a system service, make sure you are connected to something and get the SSID:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(wifiInfo.getSupplicantState()) == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
    String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
}
```

Comment: If my wireless network SSID is Linksys and I go to my friend's house who also has his SSID set to Linksys, and I can connect to either one (I have the password for both), this test will be true for both places, correct? Is there a way to be sure it is MY Linksys network? Using MAC Address, perhaps?

Comment: for some reason, it doesn't work. I have to use `ConnectivityManager` and `NetworkInfo`. what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean IsWiFiConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
        .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity != null) {
      NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
      if (info != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
          if (info[i].getTypeName().equals("WIFI")
              && info[i].isConnected())
            return true;
        }
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question regarding a specific SSID.

Answer (score 1):

The best that worked for me:

Menifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Class:

```
 public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(info!=null){

                if(info.isConnected()){
                                    //Do your work. 

                                    //To check the Network Name or other info:
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                        String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();

                }
            }
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Excuse me. Do this `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE` fire when the device is switching from one SSID to another SSID?

Comment: This should fire. Cz state changes to "disconnected" and then back to "connected". I haven't checked it though