# Test Internet Connection Android

Tags: android, networking

Wish I could do a test to verify internet connection, I don't want check network state, because it only detects if I have activated internet on my device, y yo quiero revisar si es posible conectarse a internet. Something like a ping.

Comment: See shortest way to detect Internet connection it here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection/24692766#24692766

Comment: @Nepster that doesn't fulfills the purpose of the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try following:

```
public boolean checkOnlineState() {
    ConnectivityManager CManager =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo NInfo = CManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (NInfo != null && NInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

dont forget the access

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

---

else

```
if (InetAddress.getByName("www.xy.com").isReachable(timeout))
{    }
else
{    }
```

Comment: Thats works fine, but this only check if I have Activated my wifi, 3g, but I want to check if exist internet connection, eg. sometimes we connect a wifi and the internet is down and this check if i have turned on my wifi.

Comment: ok than you should use: if (InetAddress.getByName("google.com").isReachable(2000))

Comment: isConnectedOrConnecting is deprecated in API level 28. Apps should instead use the ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback API to learn about connectivity changes. ConnectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback) and ConnectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest, PendingIntent). These will give a more accurate picture of the connectivity state of the device and let apps react more easily and quickly to changes.

Answer (score 1):

It does works for me:

To verify network availability:

```
private Boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

To verify internet access:

```
public Boolean isOnline() {
    try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
        int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
        boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
        return reachable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your method to verify inernet acces worked for me... Except for Android 4.3 jellybean, I dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code to check internet connection, it check all the internet connection over device. And Make Sure you have added Internet Permission in menifest.

```
    boolean flag=false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null)
    {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                {
                    flag=true;

                }

    }
    if(flag==true)
    {
         Log.e("TAG","Internet Is Connected");
    }
    else
    {
          Log.e("TAG","Internet Is Not Connected");
    }
```

Comment: `getAllNetworkInfo()` requires the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission.

Comment: This method will not detect if the Wifi hotspot to which you are connecting also has internet.