# API Hook on connectivity change

Tags: android, web-services, service, architecture

I have a printer inspection app on android phone, its basic inspection form
Inspector can work on a printer inspection even if he has no internet connection,

Once the phone is back with reception/internet, I would like to submit the inspection.

I was thinking to design the app using an android service
so it will save the inspection details using sqlite, then when there is internet connection to resubmit the inspection .

But this require service to periodically check for internet. and will consume significant battery juice.

Is there a hook I can register for my app to notify the app or the service on internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple check for both **Wi-fi** and **Mobile** internet as follows...


in **Manifest.xml** :

```
<receiver android:name=".com.yourapp.ConnectivityChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

make a new **BroadcastReceiver** :

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if(checkInternet(context))
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

    }

    boolean checkInternet(Context context) {
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager(context);
        if (serviceManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally **ServiceManager** class :

```
public class ServiceManager {

    Context context;

    public ServiceManager(Context base) {
        context = base;
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

** Don't forget to add permission to use the Internet in your **manifest** file :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also check out this super cool article on vogella.com [*AndroidServices*](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html) ...