# Checking network status

Tags: java, android, xml, networking, redirect

I would like to make a page that would automatically check the user's current network status when the application is started-up, and redirect the user to different page. When there is no network was connected, it will redirect the user to a specific page (eg. no_network_connected.xml). Otherwise, it will bring the user to the (main.xml) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this method checks whether mobile is connected to internet and returns true if connected:

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  if (ni == null) {
   // There are no active networks.
   return false;
  } else
   return true;
 }
```

in manifest,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

from [Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

Comment: so, how can I use this method to let the activity automatic redirect to different pages according to the network state?

Comment: This is another question, maybe you need to start with java basis than going through android application directly.