# How to Detect internet connectivity on my android App?

Tags: android, web-applications

error -2 internet connection availibality code? plz help me thanks
i am using this for android application
i need to put a code that checks the internet availibity and then it should give me an error message that ur not connected if i am not connected thanks

Comment: deplicated Have a Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection

Comment: yes sir, i didnt see that sorry

Answer (score 0):

> **This function will help you to check network is connected or not.**

```
public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context cntx) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ((Activity) cntx)
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
             Toast.makeText(cntx, "No Network Connection ! ",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: r u sure bro, wont this code interfere with any of other codings that i did on my project...?

Comment: Don't worry.It's super stable.