# Show "No internet connection" screen when app can't connect

Tags: android

What I need is that when a user opens my app and he or she hasn't got any internet connection the webview displays a screen I designed in Photoshop. So basically instead of the standard no internet error

Here's my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="false"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/vu"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3486775169258180/1572732950" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is java class -

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "BebasNeue Light.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is your code to do that? Can you please show it?

Comment: Edited it, have a look

Comment: And where are you checking for the Internet Connection?

Comment: I am not I think haha

Comment: You can find the code to do so in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection

Comment: So what is your issue, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like:

```
private boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
    boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                haveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
}
```