# Check mobile is connected with Internet using android

Tags: android

**Check connection is Available**

is there a way to find out if the device is connected to the Internet and then start activity else toast a message when click on the button.

Comment: Did you [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection) before you ask ;)?

Comment: yes i searched and applied many codes but app cursh when i run on emulator

Comment: provide proper internet permissions..

Comment: Then it would be a good idea to share some code

Comment: i want if connection is available then start activity else toast the message  ` protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
  enterForJoke=(Button)findViewById(R.id.welcomeBtn);
          final Intent intent=new Intent(this,Jokecatagory.class);
          
          enterForJoke.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startActivity(intent);
   }
   
  });//end of the On Click Listner
  
  
 }
`

Comment: i am sorry i don't know how to paste code in comment box hope you understand sorry to say that.

Comment: Edit the question and add your code over there. And as far as I can see, there's no code of yours, which checks for the connection. Also, as your application is crashing, post the logcat too in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Android's Developer pages, here is a sort example:

You need to have these two permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then you can do something like the following to check network connectivity:

```
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // start your activity here
} else {
    // display your toast here
}
```

For a more extended example you can see here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: While the URL, may answer the question, it is not a good practice to post them as answers. The URL might change in future and it might not be accessible to some users in certain scenarios. Instead, post the relevant code from the URL, which might solve the issue as per you. And you can give the URL as a reference.

Comment: Edited it @PrerakSola , my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isNetworkAvailable())
{
       Network is here..write your code here
}
else 
{
    // Notify user they aren't connected
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You aren't connected to the internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}  


private boolean isNetworkAvailable() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

use this method,if netwok available than it return "true", otherwise "false" of boolean type..

Comment: What is `Splash_Screen` ?

Comment: It is your Activity Name.

Comment: brother really i don't know what's splash screen kindly explain it pls .