# Method to check internet connection android from fragment?

Tags: android

How can I `check internet connection` from all the `fragment` I have? I just can't get it to work with all the samples online, some are hard to understand. Also I have declared all the `permission` for checking internet status on `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: As you said all the fragments. I think you need to create a static class to get internet connection status visit http://stackoverflow.com/a/33256406/2032561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet check if there is a `network` connection active, returning true or false. You can put this in a fragment called `BaseFragment` and then extends BaseFragment from the `fragments` you wish to use the code.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

protected boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return (mNetworkInfo == null) ? false : true;

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            return false;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for checking your internet connection:

```
 public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your manifest add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[EventBus is a library](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) that simplifies communication between different parts of your application. For example, sending something from an Activity to a running Service, or easy interaction between fragments. Here is an example we use if the Internet connection is lost, showing how to notify an activity:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // post event if there is no Internet connection
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        if(intent.getExtras()!=null) {
            NetworkInfo ni=(NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(ni!=null && ni.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                // there is Internet connection
            } else if(intent
                .getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY,Boolean.FALSE)) {
                // no Internet connection, send network state changed
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new NetworkStateChanged(false));
            }
}

// event
public class NetworkStateChanged {

    private mIsInternetConnected;

    public NetworkStateChanged(boolean isInternetConnected) {
        this.mIsInternetConnected = isInternetConnected;
    }

    public boolean isInternetConnected() {
        return this.mIsInternetConnected;
    }
}

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EventBus.getDefault().register(this); // register EventBus
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this); // unregister EventBus
    }

    // method that will be called when someone posts an event NetworkStateChanged
    public void onEventMainThread(NetworkStateChanged event) {
        if (!event.isInternetConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code Hope its solve your problem**

```
   private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
      = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
```

}