# Prevent WebView from displaying “No Internet!”

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a web view in my app in android studio. I have a web view in my app and I want to make a popup saying "no internet" if there is no internet and a "ok" button on the popup which will recheck if there is no internet and if there is internet it will let the web page load and if not it says "no internet". I am a beginner programmer so please keep the code simple

My Code: (mainactivity)

```
package com.myworldrules.test.testno;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://space.myworldrules.com/");


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



    }

}
```

Please feel free to ask any questions

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by accessing the ConnectivityManager and requesting the active network info.   That alone may not always be sufficient so you can additionally determine if a site like google is accessible(in case there is a chance the server you are trying to access is down).  Please see the link below;

[Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is active network connection, if it's not there you can do something like

```
            webView.loadData("", null, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is internet available or not before loading url in to webview and

if available

load  url  in webview

else

create alert dialog  for popup

to check internet connection  follow this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Just use, it should work:

```
mWebview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,htmlContent,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```