# Android studio emulator connection status

Tags: java, android

I have a method to detect connection status

```
boolean isInternetAvailable(WebView view) {
    Boolean connected = false;

    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) view.getContext()
                .getSystemService(view.getContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() &&
                networkInfo.isConnected();

        Log.d("available", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.isAvailable()));
        Log.d("connected", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.isConnected()));
        Log.d("compare", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED));

        return connected;

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return connected;
}
```

but when i disconnect all internet cables from my computer, and i can't load any page actually, emulator still thinks what he is connected and returns

```
  11-21 13:43:22.103 20824-20824/lt.example.app D/available: true
  11-21 13:43:22.103 20824-20824/lt.example.app D/connected: true
  11-21 13:43:22.103 20824-20824/lt.example.app D/compare: true
```

to console, this method used in WebViewClient to detect connection while using WebView, what can be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, your emulator does not *really* care about your actual connection status on your machine. You probably need to enable/disable the airplane mode on the emulator to get *correct* results.

As long as your emulator has wifi/data enabled it will tell you *yeah, i'm connected* even if you can't reach the internet.

If you want to check for a working connection, please see: [Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection) (`isInternetAvailable()`)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new object:

```
boolean isInternetAvailable(WebView view) {
Boolean connected = false;

try {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) view.getContext()
            .getSystemService(view.getContext().CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = new NetworkInfo();
    networkInfo=connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() &&
            networkInfo.isConnected();

    Log.d("available", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.isAvailable()));
    Log.d("connected", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.isConnected()));
    Log.d("compare", Boolean.toString(networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED));

    return connected;

} catch (Exception e) {

}

return connected;
```

}