# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1, if airplane mode is activated

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, fatal-error

I use an AsyncTask for get-requests with my server.
Everythink works fine, if i have connection to the internet, but if I activate airplane mode I get a FATAL EXCEPTION:

```
01-11 16:01:56.602 3456-3456/com.me.myapp E/ApiHelper: Error at 
getting WuerdestDu Stats. Id: 19
01-11 16:01:56.603 3456-3522/com.me.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL 
EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                               Process: com.me.myapp, PID: 3456
```

And the strange thing is, that this is the complete Error log at Logcat in verbose mode and no Filters.

This is where i use the AsyncTask:

```
try {
    response = new ApiGetHelper().execute(path).get();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error at getting WuerdestDu Stats. Id: " + question.getId(), e);
}
```

this is my AsyncTask:

```
public class ApiGetHelper extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
private final static String TAG = ApiGetHelper.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    String urlString = strings[0];

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();

        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 300) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Response: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + ": " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Response: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode() + ": " + urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }

        return ApiUtils.readResponseAsString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("URL-ERROR", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("IO-ERROR", e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Simply you have to check, is your application connected to network or not. If not show a message to user or anything else, if yes then perform your task.

Comment: off-topic comment ... using `AsyncTask.get` is terrible idea ... in fact if you use `get` why on hell you did use `AsyncTask` at first place as `get` makes `AsyncTask` synchronous (and if the cause is NetworkOnMainThreadException then you could disable the guard - as both solutions (AsyncTask.get and disable the guard) are terrible in the same way - and should be avoided)

Comment: Yes. You should not use .get(). And then you should not let doInBackground() throw exceptions if it catches one. Just return e.getMessage() then and display the info in a Toast() in onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn on aeroplane mode you are going to lose internet, you need to check that there is an active internet connection available before trying to post to your server.

Something like the following should do the trick

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
 }
```

ref: [Android check internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection)