# how i can Validate the Browser links in Android App using appium in java

Tags: java, android, appium

i have automated an Android app, now i am facing a problem,  in my app, I want to validate that browser links are working fine when user will click on the links when i click on it then the browser is opened can I validate these links without any click on it?just i want to check these are not broken links? any one can suggest me that how i can handle this problem , [image]

Comment: If you have the links, you can do a similar work around to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/2889347, you kind of ping the address.

Comment: Thanks for your dedication i have not checked the internet connection i want to check the Links are wehter they are working fine or not