# Is there a way to detect internet connectivity change when phone is connected to wifi over hotspot?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-connectivitymanager

Phone A has mobile data ON and is sharing internet via Wi-Fi hotspot to Phone B. If Mobile Data is TURNED OFF in phone A, no connectivity change is received @PhoneB. How can I get this change in Phone B when mobile data is turned ON/OFF in Phone A? 
Phone B is Android phone.

Comment: If internet is working or not to check in B phone you have to I ping a sever. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570237/android-check-internet-connection

Comment: @rajahsekar I don't want to recursively check for internet. If I get any broadcast that something has changed, I can use your solution.

Comment: There is a broadcast for only connectivity change. To check internet you have to ping some server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Simply register BroadcastReceiver for connectivity changes:

```
 @Override
public void register(Context context) {
      receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (isOnline()) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.onConnected();
                }
                hideNoConnectionError();
            } else {
                showNoConnectionError();
            }
        }
    };
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
}
```

and on change event check whatever connectivity change there was

Comment: Receiver isn't called when mobile data is turned ON/OFF in Phone A.
Reason: Wi-fi connection is intact, only internet access is not there.