# How can I check if user has blocked internet for my app?

Tags: android

Some vendors provide option to block internet for individual apps so I want to check if user has blocked internet for my app or not. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: How to user can block network? Maybe better check network connection?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570292/12771929

Comment: @SyoritoHatsuki, Some vendors provide "restrict data usage" option to block internet, Checking network connection will only show that user is not connected to internet but I want to know if user has restricted the internet.

Comment: Something new, interesting